# Calculating all combinations of 10 sets, 7 of which have 3 options and 3 have 2 options

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

My wholesale business carries $10$ brands and all customers are assigned a price tier for each of the $10$ brands. $3$ of the brands have $2$ price tiers (Tier $A$ and $B$) and $7$ of the brands have $3$ price tiers $(A, B, C)$.

Example: Jane Doe might be assigned Price Tier $A$ for all $10$ brands while John Doe is assigned $A$ for $3$ of the brands, $B$ for six brands and $C$ for $1$ brand.

If I created a price list for each scenario, I want to know how many price lists would be needed.

Would it be $3\times 3\times3\times3\times3\times3\times3\times2\times2\times2$ (or $23,328$)?

Ultimately, I am trying to find a WooCommerce plugin that can handle this many price lists but first need to know how many price lists we're talking about. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean $2^3 \cdot 3^7$ (two choices for each of the three brands with two price tiers and three choices for each of the seven brands with three price tiers)?

Comment: $23328 = 2^5 \times 3^6,~$ while the LHS of the equation represents $~2^3 \times 3^7 = 17496.~$  $17496~$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since the pricing of each brand is independent , you need to multiply the choices for each brand, eg for the $3$ brands which have only $2$ tier pricing,

$2\times 2 \times 2 = 2^3 = 8$ ways

Similarly, for the $3$ tier pricing brands,$\;3^7$ ways,

and putting it all together, $\,2^3\times3^7 = 17496\,$ possible price lists